# Which Linux distribution?

Tags: ros, linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to set up ROS on a Raspberry Pi 3 and I want to do it in a way that others with perhaps less experience with Linux can replicate.  So I found some instructions to put ROS on Ubuntu MATE.   But I ended up with a full blown desktop OS complete with X11, an Office suite and web browser.  It works fine but there is an order of magnitude to much stuff on the SD card.    Yes I know how to remove packages but I'd have to document this

This Pi3 will be physically mounted inside the robot and I doubt anyone will connect a monitor and keyboard and want to run rviz on the robot. But I will ssh in and build packages and do normal debugging

My question is:  What is the most appropriate Linux distribution to start with if the goal is a headless embedded Pi3 based ROS/Linux system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248117/which-linux-distribution?/) by [chrisalbertson](https://answers.ros.org/users/21344/chrisalbertson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2016-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that you really want a different distro. The main development platform for ROS is Ubuntu and also well supported is Debian. There are lots of variations on a theme for derivatives, but what you really want are alternative installers that have a smaller default set of packages instead of a different distribution

As a first pass you can use the Ubuntu Server installers for an install optimized for headless operations. And if you want more control you can use the network installer. See https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

And of course since it's linux you can do way more such as create your own custom image to install. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization or here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

Or use the Debian variant: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1